# using mathematical induction to prove two recursive function

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I have two function which are

$$\begin{align*}
&T_1(n)=2T_1\left(\frac{n}2\right)+n\\\\
&T_2(n)=\begin{cases}
\frac{n(n-1)}2,&\text{if }n<8\\\\
2T_2\left(\frac{n}2\right),&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\\\
&T_1(0)=T_2(0)=0\;.
\end{align*}$$

I have to prove that $T_2 < T_1$ for $k \ge 3$ and $n = 2^k$.

I have use the $n = 8$ as base and induction it from $n = 2^k$; then try to prove it from the $n = 2^k$ to $n = 2^{k + 1}$; but I it only will be equal, and I cannot figure out how it correct it.

Any hint give to me will be gratefully.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k=3$ and $n=8$ you have $T_2(8)=2T(4)=12$ and $$T_1(8)=2T(4)+8=2T(2)+12=2T(1)+14\;;$$ your recurrence doesn’t actually define $T_1(1)$, but I assume that it’s intended to be at least $0$, so $T_2(8)<T_1(8)$.

Now suppose that $T_2(2^k)<T_1(2^k)$ for some $k\ge 3$; that’s your induction hypothesis, and you want to use it to show that $T_2(2^{k+1})<T_1(2^{k+1})$. Now

$$T_2(2^{k+1})=2T_2\left(\frac{2^{k+1}}2\right)=2T_2(2^k)\;,$$

and

$$T_1(2^{k+1})=2T_1\left(\frac{2^{k+1}}2\right)+2^{k+1}=2T_1(2^k)+2^{k+1}\;.$$

Can you put the pieces together now to conclude that $T_2(2^{k+1})<T_1(2^{k+1})$?

I’ve done the rest of it below but left it spoiler-protected; mouse-over to see it if you get stuck.

> The key calculation is $$T_2(2^{k+1})=2T_2(2^k)\overset{*}<2T_1(2^k)<2T_1(2^k)+2^{k+1}=T_1(2^{k+1})\;,$$ where the starred inequality follows from the induction hypothesis. That completes the induction step, and you can now conclude that $T_2(2^k)<T_1(2^k)$ for all $k\ge 3$.